# Varnish with multiple backends serves stale content during deploy

Tags: deployment, assets, varnish, varnish-vcl

We use Varnish in front of 10 Nginx servers that server HTML+CSS. CSS url is formatted like this: "file-HASH.css" (with HASH a content checksum).

When we deploy (from version A to B) the application, this takes a few time, during this (couple of seconds), end-user can download 2 versions of HTML:

- version A => "file-A.css" (already in varnish cache)
- version B => "file-B.css" (present only on some backends)

No problem for version A: file-A.css is cached.

Problem with version B: Varnish could fetch the file from a backend that is not already deployed! then return a 404.

I see some solutions:

- retry until css file is found => could create ddos
- disable backends not deployed during deployment via varnishadm
- use a single backend to store assets => not H.A.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do. You could spin up a new set of environments servers, put a load balancer behind Varnish, deploy new version to one of the server groups and then route the traffic to new group (green-blue).

However the simplest solution will be to decouple the deployment the release. First deploy a version that has all the new css files and then other turn a flag in the database or deploy the code that uses those files. Splitting your release into two parts may be a bit primitive however it will ensure the resource are there when Varnish asks for them.